# Laravel fortify verify email using rest API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-fortify

I am using fortify for the user authentication and management. I am making a rest api application and I want to use `use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\VerifyEmailController` or implement `VerifyEmailResponse` but what I get is that `route [login] not defined`

I dont have a `/login` route since im creating a rest API `/api/login`

Here is what my FortifyServiceProvider looks like

```
public function register (): void
{
        $this->app->instance(VerifyEmailResponse::class, new class implements VerifyEmailResponse {
            public function toResponse($request)
            {   
                if ($request->user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
                    return response()->ok(null, __('Email already verified.'));
                }
                
                $request->user->markEmailAsVerified();
                event(new Verified($request->user));
                
                return response()->ok(null, __('Email successfully verified!'));
            }
        });
}
```

It doesnt return the response I want and it redirects me to login route. I created a working solution using a specific controller that returns the correct response. I think its identical to the controller used by Fortify

```
class EmailVerificationController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->route('id'));

        if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->ok(null, __('Email already verified.'));
        }
        
        $user->markEmailAsVerified();
        event(new Verified($user));
        
        return response()->ok(null, __('Email successfully verified!'));

    }
}
```

I call it by

```
 Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, '__invoke'])->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('verification.verify');
```

Is it possible to use the fortify feature or it needs to be customized like what I did?

Answer (score 1):

one thing you could do is to first ignore the fortify routes in fortifyServiceProvider.php in **register** method like below:

```
public function register(){
     Fortify::ignoreRoutes();
}
```

in your fortify.php:

```
 'prefix' => 'api',
```

in your web.php you can create a route and call fortify controller:

```
 Route::get('api/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [\Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('verification.verify');
```

or if you want you can create a controller and extend it from fortify controllers.
i came up with this solution. i hope it helps you. please let me know if this will fix your problem or not.

Comment: If I ignore the fortify routes, i cant use other routes like login and register right?

Comment: correct. you have to create it manually @draw134

Comment: i am utilizing some fortify routes so unfortunately this wont work right?

Comment: yes this wont work. but you if your problem is with the api prefix you can kind of handle it in the service provider if statements @draw134. 
you can simply change the prefix key in fortify.php config based on your route name or other conditions